# How can I connect to the VMware virtual machine, that is located at the another host machine using ssh

Tags: ssh, vmware, esxi

I have 2 host machines in a single network (On the First One I'm using workstation pro 15, which runs ESXI Hypervisor, and on top of that I have Virtual Machine), on the Second one, I have a backend Application, that interacts with this Virtual Machine, (so my question is: How can I Connect to this VM with static IP, which runs on the ESXI Hypervisor on the another host machine, from my backend application using SSH ?  (That's probably sounds a bit complicated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentionned that it's on same network, the easiest way is to make the VM network interface bridged.
This will make VM IP adress in the same network of the host machines.
And you can SSH from any VM to the other.